# Reading a set amount of Columns with Apache-POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Here's the jist of what I'm doing.

I'm creating an ExcelProcessor object which then takes the file I specify in the constructor.  After this I retrieve the books, rows, and then cells in the rows.  The first Row has the name of what each column holds data wise.  Unfortunately if any cell is blank in a row it stops processing right then and there.  Is there a way to say read X number of columns in each row?

Thanks!

```
public class ExcelProcessor
{
    private static File xslFile;

    ExcelProcessor( String file )
    {
        xslFile = new File(file);
    }

    /**
     * creates an {@link HSSFWorkbook} the specified OS filename.
     */

    /**
     * Returns an XSSF Workbook object that can be queried. 
     * 
     * This method either returns a Workbook with the specified
     * file location or it will throw an IO Error.
     *
     * @return      the Excel Workbook 
     * @see         XSSFWB
     */

    private XSSFWorkbook readFile() throws IOException
    {
        return new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(xslFile));
    }

    /**
     * Returns all rows of the XSSF Workbook that is read in via the file system.
     * 
     * This method returns a XSSFRow array for processing
     *
     * @param   wb  the Excel workbook located on the file system
     * @return      Rows contained within the Excel Workbook
     * @see         XSSFRows
     */

    private XSSFRow[] retrieveRows(XSSFWorkbook wb)
    {
        XSSFSheet xslSheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFRow[] sheetRows = new XSSFRow[xslSheet.getLastRowNum()];

        for (int i = 0; i < xslSheet.getLastRowNum(); i++)
        {
            sheetRows[i] = xslSheet.getRow(i);
        }

        return sheetRows;
    }

    private XSSFWorkbook modifyRows(XSSFWorkbook wb)
    {
        return wb;
    }

    /**
     * Processes all rows of the XSSF Workbook that is read in via the file system.
     * Each Cell is pulled from the rows to create a structure needed for WQS 
     * Web Services.
     * 
     * This method returns a String array for all Cells pulled from the Rows
     *
     * @param   xslRow  Current row pulled from the XSL Workbook
     * @return      String Array of all Row Cell Values
     * @see         String[]
     */

    public String[] processRow(XSSFRow xslRow)
    {
        int totalCells = xslRow.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
        System.out.println("Total Cells: " + totalCells);
        String[] cellValues = new String[totalCells];

        for (int i = 0; i < totalCells; i++)
        {
            XSSFCell currentCell = xslRow.getCell(i);
            String cellVal;
            try
            {
                cellVal = currentCell.getStringCellValue();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Empty Cell");
                cellVal = "";
            }
            cellValues[i] = cellVal;
            System.out.println(cellVal);
        }

        return cellValues;
    }

    /**
     * Main method which creates an ExcelProcessor before handling the Excel
     * Spreadsheet given to the user.
     * 
     * @param args
     * @throws ParserConfigurationException
     * @throws SAXException
     */

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException
    {
        ExcelProcessor driver = new ExcelProcessor("D:\\TestBook.xlsx");

        try
        {
            XSSFWorkbook xslWB = driver.readFile();
            XSSFRow[] xslRows = driver.retrieveRows(xslWB);
            ArrayList<String[]> rowCellVals = new ArrayList<String[]>();

            for (int r = 0; r < xslRows.length; r++)
            {
                rowCellVals.add(driver.processRow(xslRows[r]));
            }

            String sessionKey = WQSServices.sessionToken();
            System.out.println("Have the Session Key: " + sessionKey);
            WQSServices.uploadAttachment(sessionKey, rowCellVals);

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [getLastCellNum](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.html#getLastCellNum%28%29) instead, `getPhysicalNumberOfCells` returns number of cells(not counting empty ones)

Comment: Even with using getLastCellNum I receive a number which does not include the spaces.  How does it know to grab empty cells?  Does the getLastCellNum end with the last filled cell?

Comment: I assume that the empty cells are in the end of row. Then the simplest solution is to get the number of cells in the first row(the one, which  holds column names) and pass it to `processRow` as `totalCells`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you shouldn't just blindly try to read a string as a cell and catch an exception. Instead, you should check if it is defined or not in the file (is it null?), and check the type of it. Your sheet could well contain numbers, and they're not stored as strings so your current code will skip them!

I would suggest you read through the [Iterating over Rows and Cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) and [Reading Cell Contents](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents) sections of the POI quick-guide as starters. Then, change your code to be more like:

```
// Decide which rows to process
int rowStart = Math.min(15, sheet.getFirstRowNum());
int rowEnd = Math.max(1400, sheet.getLastRowNum());

for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
   Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);

   int lastColumn = Math.max(r.getLastCellNum(), MY_MINIMUM_COLUMN_COUNT);

   for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
      Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
      if (c == null) {
         // The spreadsheet is empty in this cell
      } else {
         // Do something useful with the cell's contents
         switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                    System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
                } else {
                    System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                }
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                System.out.println(cell.getCellFormula());
                break;
         }     
      }
   }
}
```